# Can't install package with NPM behind proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to install Electron in NPM , using this command:

```
npm install --save-dev electron
```

But I always got :

```
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: read ECONNRESET
```

I configured the file `.npmrc` with following configs:

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
proxy=http://mycompany.proxy:8080/
https-proxy=http://mycompany.proxy:8080/
```

But didn't resolve. I tried follow this guide: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/installation#proxies. So added `ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY` but same error.

I'm running npm within a MacOS BigSur.